# Pygame: Method for a test of collision between entities

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game in pygame, and I wish to have a player that is affected by gravity.

And I need a code that can act like this-

if player is not colliding with block:
      player.y=player.y+1

So when there is a block under it, don't fall.. but otherwise do fall.

Here is the code as a whole:

```
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
class Block(object):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("texture\\dirt.png").convert_alpha()
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)

class Player(object):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("texture\\playr.png").convert()
    sprite.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)

blocklist = []
player = []

while True:
    screen.fill((25,30,90))
    mse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: exit()
        key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_LSHIFT]:
            if event.type==MOUSEMOTION:
                x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                blocklist.append(Block(x+16,y+16))
        else:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:
                    to_remove = [b for b in blocklist if b.rect.collidepoint(mse)]
                    for b in to_remove:
                        blocklist.remove(b)

                    if not to_remove:
                        x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                        y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                        blocklist.append(Block(x+16,y+16))

                elif event.button == 3:
                    x=(int(mse[0]) / 32)*32
                    y=(int(mse[1]) / 32)*32
                    player=[]
                    player.append(Player(x+16,y+16))

    for b in blocklist:
        screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)
    for p in player:
        if p.rect.colliderect(blocklist):
            print 'scoof'
        screen.blit(p.sprite, p.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `print 'scoof'` with `p.rect.top += 1`.

Comment: The error is raised from `if p.rect.colliderect(blocklist):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `blocklist` is not a Rect, it is a list of Rects. `colliderect` only takes in a Rect, but you gave it a list. Here is a solution that will work:

```
for p in player:
    if any(p.rect.colliderect(block) for block in blocklist):
        print 'scoof'
    else:
        p.rect.top += 1
    screen.blit(p.sprite, p.rect)
```

That will see if any of the blocks in `blocklist` are colliding with the player. If they are, it will print 'scoof', otherwise it will move the player one pixel down the screen.

Comment: ! You've done it! Thanks :)  and thanks for your help too @Shashank!

Comment: Instead of `if any(p.rect.colliderect(block) for block in blocklist):`, just use `if p.rect.collidelist(blocklist):`.

Answer (score 1):

`colliderect` is supposed to take a rectangle argument. In your code you are passing it a whole list of blocks (blocklist) so it doesn't know what to do with it. Try this code and let me know if it works.

EDIT: Oops fixed a few potential errors.

```
for b in blocklist:
    screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)
for p in player:
    colliding = False
    for b in blocklist:
        if p.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
            colliding = True
    if not colliding:
        p.rect.top += 1
    screen.blit(p.sprite, p.rect)

pygame.display.update()
```

And here is the [documentation for `colliderect`.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

Comment: Made a few little changes to it.. but it served the purpose perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I did this:
`for b in blocklist:
        screen.blit(b.sprite, b.rect)
    for p in player:
        if not p.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
            p.rect.top += 1
    for p in player:
        screen.blit(p.sprite,p.rect)
    pygame.display.update()`

Comment: Oh and one more question.. how can I make him fall slower?

Comment: Oh no.. another problem has arisen :(

Comment: @SamTubb `p.rect.top += 0.1` would be the simplest way. But you should actually make your speed scale off time so that your game will stay consistent even with slower computers. You'll need the Pygame.Clock module to do that. What's the problem?

Comment: The player can only collide with one block.. go paste the code and see for yourself :(

Comment: @SamTubb I had another logical error in my code. If colliderect returned false, I was setting `colliding` to True. Anyways it should work now if you use my code. :) And by the way I can't paste your code since I don't have your images.

Comment: I'll try it out. And you could just draw your own little 32x32 png images.

Comment: @Sam that's way too much effort. I am a lazy cat.

Comment: Nope. He still just slips right through any block that wasn't just placed.

Comment: @Sam ok one second im setting it up

Comment: The other guy fixed it! Thanks for your help though.. I wish I could add you to some contact list. You seem to know what you are talking about!